# changing the data-icon in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

How would I update the data-icon attribute in Javascript?

```
document.getElementById("btn").data-icon = "&#xe082";
```

This does not work, as it would for style, or width or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.setAttribute();` for setting attributes to elements

`document.getElementById("btn").setAttribute("data-icon", "&#xe082");`

Also, you cannot use `-` when calling objects as it thinks you are trying to subtract, unless you call it like `obj['key-name'];`

Comment: Thanks this makes the change, but rather than changing the icon the string "&#xe082" shows up, any idea why? also with that same string an icon loads on page load, just not when updated via JS

Comment: @wazzaday, I would replace `&#xe082` with its unicode alternative e.g.`\uE00A` You can use this to look it up http://unicodelookup.com/

Comment: instead of `"&#xe082"`, use `"\E082"`

Answer (score 3):

It's an attribute, and for attributes it's `setAttribute()`

```
document.getElementById("btn").setAttribute('data-icon', '&#xe082');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.setAttribute();` for setting attributes to elements:

```
document.getElementById("btn").setAttribute("data-icon", "&#xe082");
```

Also, you cannot use `-` when calling objects, as it thinks you are trying to subtract, unless you call it like `obj['key-name'];`.