# Changing HTML embedded Code in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, embedding

What I'm Trying to do is to have a text field and a button, and create usernames, so when the user opens the first view he will be asked to enter his username. I created multiple chat rooms from a free service online and saved their embadable code.

The code for the embedable chat room:

```
      <div id="tlkio" data-channel="lobby" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
      <script async src="http://tlk.io/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

basically what I want to change from all of this is the date-channel I want it to change for example from "lobby" to "Mentors"

I Tried this:

```
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" >
       var x;
       function func() {
       var r = document.getElementById("tlkio");
       var a = document.getElementById("entr");
       switch(a)
       {
          case "username1":
          r.data-channel="lobby";
          break;
          case "username2":
          r.data-channel="mentors";
          break;
          default:
          void(0);
       }
          }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form>
       <input type="text" id="entr">
       <input type="button" onclick="func()" value="go">
       <div id="tlkio" data-channel="lobby" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
      <script async src="http://tlk.io/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </form>
 </body>
```

And with no luck, I tried creating an empty div, and then embed all the embedable chat code in the javascript code, but it didn't work either. I searched for solutions but also with no luck :(
I really appreciate any help I could take with this problem.

Comment: Look in the browser's error console to see the error messages. That should give the first step forward.

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing the data-icon in pure javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133089/changing-the-data-icon-in-pure-javascript)